# How can I improve these 8051 arch instructions?

Tags: optimization, assembly, 8051

I'm writing to memory space a few address and I need to optimize the code. There is a better way to do the following?

```
SETB 00h
SETB 01h
SETB 02h
SETB 03h
SETB 04h
SETB 05h
SETB 06h
SETB 07h
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you want to do is:

```
MOV 20h,#0FFh
```

this should be equivalent to setting each byte

Answer (score 2):

I see techspecs and indirect adress is better for change

```
MOV @R0,#0FFh
```